# Error drawing a choropleth map with plotly

Tags: python, layout, plotly, plotly-dash, choropleth

I'm new in Plotly. I'm trying to draw a choropleth map with this tool. I have my data in a database and I'm trying to show some of them in a map.
First, I launch my das application : `app = dash.Dash()`
Once I'm connected to the database, I execute the following code:

```
#Load dataframes
df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM Companies_Public', con=db_connection)

#Choropleth map
app.layaout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
        id = 'Map',
        figure={
            'data': [ dict(
                    type = 'choropleth',
                    locations = df['ISOCountry'],
                    z = sum(df['FinalPointsPerDemography']),
                    text = df['CountryName'],
                    colorscale = [[0,"rgb(5, 10, 172)"],[0.35,"rgb(40, 60, 190)"],[0.5,"rgb(70, 100, 245)"],\
                        [0.6,"rgb(90, 120, 245)"],[0.7,"rgb(106, 137, 247)"],[1,"rgb(220, 220, 220)"]],
                    autocolorscale = False,
                    reversescale = True,
                    marker = dict(
                        line = dict (
                            color = 'rgb(180,180,180)',
                            width = 0.5
                        ) ),
                    colorbar = dict(
                        autotick = False,
                        tickprefix = '$',
                        title = 'Points<br>'),
                  ) ],

            'layout': go.Layout(
                title = 'Points by Company per Demography',
                geo = dict(
                    showframe = False,
                    showcoastlines = False,
                    projection = dict(
                        type = 'Mercator'
                    )
                )
            )
        }
    )
])

# Add the server clause:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

I get the next message in the console:

dash.exceptions.NoLayoutException: The layout was `None` at the time that `run_server` was called. Make sure to set the `layout` attribute of your application before running the server.

The following figure shows the structure of df:
[df structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUYMm.png)

Comment: Is it this typo? `app.layaout`

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. Thanks! However the dashboard only shows the title, but not the choropleth map

Comment: Who does your dataframe `df` look like? Can you provide a few lines to get a [MCVE]?

Comment: I added an image above